# Plotting/Representing function of complex variable in matlab

Tags: complex-analysis, matlab

I am studying the *principle of argument* in control system, and I have this function

$f(s) = \frac {1}{s^2-5s+6}  $

I want to plot this function for $ |s| = 1 $ i.e. a unit circle in s domain.

I get the transfer function using

```
G = zpk([],[2,3],1);
```

I tried creating a (HALF)unit circle with

```
x=linspace(-1,1);
y=sqrt(1-x.^2);
```

I could represent **s** as **x**+*i***y**, but then **how would i put it in $ f(s) $**, should I be using the *TF* ?

Kindly suggest me the proper method to do this.

Comment: Would this question be better suited for stackoverflow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by using polar representation of $s$, i.e. $s = re^{i\varphi}$ with $r = |s| = 1$. With this method you don't need the control toolbox.

Substituting $s$ with $e^{i\varphi}$ in your function gives

$$f(e^{i\varphi})=\frac1{(e^{i\varphi}-2)(e^{i\varphi}-3)}$$

Now just calculate values for $\varphi$ in the range $[0, 2\pi]$.

Note that the resulting values are complex, so you need to choose how to visualize them. You can for example plot the real and imaginary values or the modulus and arguments.

```
phi = linspace(0, 2*pi);
f = 1./((exp(i*phi)-2).*(exp(i*phi)-3));
figure
plot(phi,real(f)); hold on; plot(phi,imag(f),'r');
figure
plot(phi,abs(f)); hold on; plot(phi,angle(f),'r');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
colormap(hsv(64));
z = cplxgrid(30);
cplxmap(z,1./(z.^2-5.*z+6));
```

see [here](http://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab/examples.html?file=/products/demos/shipping/matlab/cplxdemo.html) for more details.

Comment: This gave me a 3d plot. It seems fantastic. I'm going through the link you provided.

Comment: Yes, in 3-d the real part of the function is the height of surface and imaginary part of the function is the color of surface.

Comment: How do you interpret the magnitude from color? Is there some chart? Also what role does 30 plays in cplxgrid(30)? Couldn't find it in that page!

Comment: "CPLXGRID(n) is an $(n+1)x(2n+1)$ complex polar grid".
Try 10 instead of 30 you will see the difference it is about the points in the grid.

Comment: "Domain coloring", google it.